# How to use biblatex with miktex and texmaker

Tags: miktex, texmaker, windows

I try to write my thesis with LaTeX. I built a basic template which seems to work. But, now I want to use `biblatex` for autor-year citations. And this doesn't seem to work in my case. I'm getting errors which makes no sense to me.

These are the error-messages which `texmaker` shows me:

[image: errors]

And this is my code:

```
%-------------------------
% Dokumentenart festlegen
%-------------------------
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

%-------------------------
% Pakete einbinden
%-------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

%-------------------------
% Schriftart Helvetica einstellen
%-------------------------
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

%-------------------------
% Dokumenteigenschaften festlegen
%-------------------------
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=2.8cm, bottom=2.3cm]{geometry}

%-------------------------
% Literaturverzeichnis festlegen
%-------------------------
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

%-------------------------
% Kopfzeile festlegen
%-------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

%-------------------------
% Abbildungsverzeichnis festlegen
%-------------------------
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,
labelsep=endash]{caption}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}}

\newcounter{savepage}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

%-------------------------
% Dokument beginnen
%-------------------------
\begin{document}

%-------------------------
% Titelseite einbinden
%-------------------------
%\input{Kapitel/titelblatt.tex}

%-------------------------
% Abbildungsverzeichnis einfügen
%-------------------------
\listoffigures
\newpage

%-------------------------
% Tabellenverzeichnis einfügen
%-------------------------
\listoftables
\newpage

%-------------------------
% Inhaltsverzeichnis einfügen
%-------------------------
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%-------------------------
% Inhalt der Arbeit
%-------------------------
\clearpage
\setcounter{savepage}{\arabic{page}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Einleitung}

%-------------------------
% Ein Bild einfügen
%-------------------------
%\begin{figure}
%\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Bilder/fomLogo.jpg}
%\caption{Ein Logo}
%\end{figure}

\subsection{Zielsetzung}

%-------------------------
% Ein Text mit Zitat
%-------------------------
\section{Grundlagen}
Hier steht ein Zitat \cite[S.102]{wurst}.

\section{Fazit}

%-------------------------
% Literaturverzeichnis
%-------------------------
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\value{savepage}}
\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here is the relevant biblatex code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Grundlagen}
Hier steht ein Zitat \cite[S.102]{wurst}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the literatur.bib:

% This file was created with Citavi 5.2.0.8

```
@book{wurst,
 author = {P{\"o}hm, Matthias},
 year = {2015},
 title = {Pr{\"a}sentieren Sie noch oder faszinieren Sie schon? Abschied vom {\dq}Betreuten Lesen{\dq} ; emotionale Rhetorik statt PowerPoint!},
 address = {Bonstetten},
 edition = {3. Auflage},
 publisher = {{P{\"o}hm Seminarfactory}},
 isbn = {3952395048}
}
```

Furthermore, I got a strange page on top of my titlpage. There are some letters like "anytanyt".

If I use the bibliography package with basic settings there are no erros and all is fine, but I need the autor-year citation. I think this is some sort of misconfiguration. But I don't get it :(.

Using Texmaker 4.4.1, MikTex 2.9 and Windows 10

UPDATE:

This is my logfile main.blg after compiling with biber.

```
[0] Config.pm:327> INFO - This is Biber 2.3
[0] Config.pm:330> INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
[61] biber-MSWIN:284> INFO - === 
[123] Biber.pm:346> INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
[242] Utils.pm:147> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 2.9
[243] Biber.pm:689> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[251] Biber.pm:3066> INFO - Processing section 0
[312] Biber.pm:3206> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'literatur.bib' for section 0
[318] bibtex.pm:1062> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[324] bibtex.pm:923> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'literatur.bib'
[427] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[427] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[428] Biber.pm:2943> INFO - Sorting list 'anyt/global' of type 'entry' with scheme 'anyt' and locale 'de-DE'
[428] Biber.pm:2947> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
[455] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[455] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[455] Biber.pm:2943> INFO - Sorting list 'anyt' of type 'entry' with scheme 'anyt' and locale 'de-DE'
[455] Biber.pm:2947> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
[458] bbl.pm:505> INFO - Writing 'main.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[458] bbl.pm:596> INFO - Output to main.bbl
[462] Biber.pm:107> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to update and synchronize my MikTex installation (it's completly new downloaded but ok...)

This is the result:

[image]

Slowly i get tired about using Tex. Maybe it's better to use a Linux VM?

*UPDATE*

The internal error which occurs if i start Update-Wizzard in Package-Manager:

MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
Data: 
Source: Programs\MiKTeX\PackageManager\MFC\MpmView.cpp
Line: 911
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 10586
Invokers: RuntimeBroker
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\sebie\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\sebie\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\sebie\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\sebie\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\sebie\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: On my machine your example complies perfectly.

Comment: since you seem to be a german speaker: http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Comment: `biblatex` has had some drastic changes. Update all packages if you the time, clear all the aux files and start over.

Comment: The Logfile tells me the following: Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 2.9. How can i downgrade the biblatex control file? Don't know how to specify the versions. Sorry guys iam new to Latex. Added Logfile in my Question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op decided to stop using LaTeX.  Therefore the issue can't be proffed longer ...