# MikTex 2.9 Package Manager internal error trying Update Wizard

Tags: miktex

I installed MikTex 2.9 on a recently fresh installed Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit. The installation had admin rights and completed without errors. Afterwards I rebooted and then tried to update packages with the package manager. This fails with an internal error:

[image: Miktex Package manager: internal error]

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
Data: 
Source: Programs\MiKTeX\PackageManager\MFC\MpmView.cpp
Line: 913
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 10586
Invokers: non-existing/explorer
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

It makes no difference if the package manager is run with sysadmin rights (except for showing SysAdmin: yes / no in the Problem Report).

I also tried uninstalling MikTex, reinstalling it with the Basic 64 Bit installer (first time I had tried the net installer). Makes no difference.

Cannot find the MemVice.cpp ... What happens in line 913 ? Any recommendations how to get this to work?

PS.: This thread seems to be related, but no solution: [How to use biblatex with miktex and texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303697/how-to-use-biblatex-with-miktex-and-texmaker)

Comment: Did you close the Package Manager before running the Update Wizard?

Comment: No chance... I opened the dropdown menu "Task" and clicked "Update Wizard". The the error appears immediately.
... but thx for your comment. I had found how to start the wizard myself in the meantime.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sorry, in retrospect the solution seems obvious... but I had been looking around for quite some time.

Do not use the Package Manager, but "MikTex Update (Admin)" :-/
Windows 10 tricked me, for when opening the start menu and typing "MikTex" it only shows the package manager.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! All's  well that ends well, as Old Bill said.

Comment: Well it is not obvious: the package manager has a menu entry  "update wizard" so imho one should expect it to work. Actually this is a long standing bug whose error message changed over the years but which never was resolved. See e.g. https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2162/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Where is the artifact 3104160 mentioned in the close comment? I'd like to read more of the cause of the issue but the numbering doesn't seem to match SourceForge's bug numbering.

Comment: You shouldn't apologize. It's very reasonable to expect main menu items in mature software to work. I had the same problem; thank you for the solution.

Comment: It is not obvious at all considering that the recommended installation is "user level"